# Boiled pork exposed to tomato sauce with molds

Tags: food-safety, sauce, tomatoes, pork, mold

I added tomato sauce in my pork dish when i noticed that the sauce has molds on it. I washed, boiled and cooked the pork again and used a new tomato sauce, is it still safe to eat?

Comment: So you noticed the mold after adding the sauce and immediately washed the meat?  Was the pork raw at that point? can you clarify?